# How convert the terraform script which are written for AWS cloud to Azure Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, terraform

Currently we have terraform script which written for AWS Provider.
Are there any tools or plug-ins which will covert/migrate these terraform files from AWS specific to Azure specific.

Answer (score 4):

No.

You've fallen for the great HashiCorp gimmick that a lot of directors and VPs fell for: "oh, this one tool is cloud agnostic! we only have to write our cloud infrastructure code once, and if we decide to migrate, we just switch out the providers". (I've actually heard a senior level director say this [at a very very large company]).

Unfortunately, you still need to understand the cloud providers underlying technology stack.